# Extracting bitcoin addresses info in batches

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

End goal is to find all used addresses of a xpub programmatically, in batches, by querying a local node.

This PHP tool ( https://github.com/dan-da/hd-wallet-addrs ) extracts regular bitcoin addresses from an HD bitcoin wallet . I have to query a local bitcoin node to find out whether the extracted addresses have been used or not.This can easily be found out by querying the node one address at a time ( https://bitco.in/en/developer-reference#getreceivedbyaddress ). It works, but is too slow.

How can the same be done in batches ? i.e is there a Core function call or something to check info about a group of addresses ?

or any other way this can be accomplished ? I am relatively new to bitcoin and don't fully understand its inner workings.

P.S: can't use an external API like blockchain.info

Answer (score 0):

With [importAddress](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#importaddress) and rescan (3 paramter) set to true, you can add the addresses that you want watch.

Than with [listTransactions](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#listtransactions) you can list the last transactions that affect the imported address.